# How to preserve tray icon position on reboot?

Tags: mac, icon, macos

The issue seems to occur after updating to macOS Sierra.

After the update, the position of the tray icons changed (from what they had been before the update). Redragging them works, but they are reset to this certain position if the system is rebooted. This didn't seem to happen before upgrading to Sierra. (Either that or the icons are somehow always placed to the position I wanted whenever I install new applications, which is unlikely)

Is there a way to make the tray icon positions persist on reboot?

I have [Bartender 2](https://www.macbartender.com/) installed, but I don't think it is causing the issue.

Comment: Bartender's sole purpose is to allow menu customizations.  Why do you think it's not causing the issue?  Have you uninstalled it and rebooted to verify?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I don't use Bartender. The makers of iStat Menus think it's an OS issue, but the 10.12.1 release didn't fix it for me either. https://bjango.com/help/istatmenus5/knownissues/

Comment: Update: turns out it was NOT an OS issue, iStat has fixed it with an update. So Bartender 2 in your case should fix it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs when using iStat Menus v5.2 (or older?) on macOS Sierra.

This issue is addressed in [iStat Menus 5.3](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/versionhistory/).